# Max/min value from certain columns referenced by index, within a row of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
+------+---+----+-----+---+---+-------+
| Name | A | B  | ... | X | Y | maxXY |
+------+---+----+-----+---+---+-------+
| John | 3 | 6  |     | 3 | 1 |       |
+------+---+----+-----+---+---+-------+
| Will | 2 | 3  |     | 4 | 4 |       |
+------+---+----+-----+---+---+-------+
| Dave | 2 | 7  |     | 3 | 2 |       |
+------+---+----+-----+---+---+-------+
| Pete | 1 | 21 |     | 2 | 3 |       |
+------+---+----+-----+---+---+-------+
```

I would like to calculate the row-wise maximum value from a selection of columns which I would **reference using the column id**. So something like this:

```
target_columns = [45,46] # X = 45, Y = 46
dataframe['maxXY'] = ...
```

Many thanks,

Comment: Don't agree that its a duplicate since I was asking to reference the column by id and not naming columns since I have over 15 columns to work with.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
dataframe['maxXY'] = np.max(dataframe.iloc[:, target_columns],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

We usually using `pandas.DataFrame.max`

```
dataframe['maxXY'] = dataframe.iloc[:, target_columns].max(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `np.max(dataframe[[dataframe.index[45],dataframe.index[46]].iloc[row_num].values)` may produce the desired results.

Comment: 1) row_num means I have to iterate through all the rows
2) this means I also have to have 'dataframe.index[..]' for each column
Surely there is a more elegant way than this

Comment: I see what you mean. Perhaps transpose your df and index rows? `df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = np.random.rand(50)
df['b'] = np.random.rand(50)
new_panda = df.transpose()
np.max(new_panda.iloc[0])`

Comment: np.max is the answer, but using iloc[:,target_cols] -see above. thanks for your help though :)